# May I re-enter UK on a marriage visa that is about to expire?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens, weddings

In my Philippine passport I have a marriage visa for the UK valid until the end of the year. May I return to the UK on that visa before it expires? Me and my fiance haven't had a chance to get married in UK as because of unexpected that he needs to go to USA for his work, that's why I am back here in Philippines, but we still have a plan to married here in Philippines.

Comment: impossible to tell, depends on the terms of the visa... You'll probably have to be married before it expires for example, which sounds like it's not going to happen. In all, your story sounds pretty much like you want to abuse your visa to gain entry into the country to stay without getting married, a massive red flag for immigration officers.

Comment: @the_cutestlink, you left out the important information! Did you get married on your previous visit? And does the entry clearance in your passport say 'MULT'? Nobody can give you a decent reply when the critical information isn't given.

Comment: No we didn't get married in my previous visa, because my fiance is unexpected need to go to USA for his work, thats why I get back here in Philippines but we want to get married soon either here in Philippines or in Spain. What's mean of 'MULT'? Gayot Fow?

Comment: MULT = multiple entry. Visas can be for a single entry, or for multiple entries within the valid time frame of the visa. If your visa doesn't state that it's a multiple entry, you may already be out of luck.

Comment: Yes it say in my Visa a MULT so that means I can still get back to UK with my visa before its expired?

Comment: [UK website](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa/eligibility) says that you must leave the UK by the end of the visa. Even if you do get married by the end of the year, do you plan to overstay the visa? That could cause problems later on.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the visa to get married *in the UK*? Why do you want to get married in Spain or in the Philippines?

Comment: The real purpose of me with my Marriage Visa is to get Married in UK, but me and my partner decided to spend a bit more time to get to know each other properly, but because he needs to  go to USA for work, that's why I get back here in Philippines. As we thought that  I won't be able to get back to UK, that's why we think to get married here in Philippines or Spain. And the reason why we want to live in Spain after we get married its because the dad of my fiance is living alone in Spain and also my partner wants to live in Spain.

Answer (score 6):

From the further information you provided in the comments, all of your questions are given in the rules...

You have a multiple entry clearance and you have NOT yet married (and presumably you have a good reason for not marrying during your last visit).  So yes, it's ok to enter again.  This is stated in Paragraph 20A of the rules.  Had you been married, then no, that would make you an illegal entrant under Paragraph 30C of the rules (entering for a different purpose than that given on the entry clearance).

Don't expect them to be happy about it.  To be fair, you can expect a thorough grilling at your landing interview on why you came and did not get married and why you think you'll get married this time. If you do not think up something that satisfies them, you will face detention under Paragraph 30A (ii) of the rules.  Also, if your plans have changed and you do NOT intend upon marrying during your visit, they will be entitled to revoke your entry clearance on the spot under Paragraph 10B of the rules.

So, yes, you can come again and stay until your entry clearance expires *IF* you have a successful landing interview.

The rules are at https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/immigration-rules